# Geometric Inference of Angles in a Triangle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry

**NOTE:** This question is related to a [puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29421/a-triangular-quidditch-field).  If you are trying to solve that puzzle and don't want to be spoiled, then don't read any answers here, assuming there are any.  In trying to solve it, I came up with this generic question which should have an answer if that puzzle is valid, but is eluding me.

You are given a triangle $\triangle ABC$ and two points on different line segments of the triangle $X$ and $Y$.  You know all the angles of $\triangle ABC$, and you know the angles at points $X$ and $Y$ involving $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Here is what you start with.

[image: Initial Triangle]

You are given:
$$\angle ABC, \angle BCA$$
$$\angle XCA, \angle YAC$$

You can then infer the remaining angles.

Call the intersection inside the triangle the point $O$.  Now draw a line from $B$ through $O$, and call the point $Z$ where this line intersects with the $AC$ line segment.

Lastly, create a new triangle $\triangle XYZ$.  It looks like this:
[image]
Obviously, this triangle is uniquely defined and it should be possible to compute its angles as well as all the angles involving point $O$.

Is there a way geometrically and/or with a system of equations to get values for all these angles as functions of the given angles?  Ideally, without using trigonometric functions in the final answers.  Specifically, the puzzle in question is asking for $\angle XYO$, and that value could be easily used to infer the others.

Comment: A formula without trigonometry (kind of like a contest question?) would be possible for some values, but probably not all, as a formula would probably have the trigonometric functions in them.

Comment: @MXYMXY That is interesting if it is true.  Some values might give rise to congruent triangles perhaps?  I've tried reflecting/rotating/extending lines etc, and can't get enough information to get the extra angles.  For example, extending line $ZY$ and $AB$ will create a new intersection point in the top left somewhere.  But that will not add any obvious value.  In fact, we could extend all the lines of the $\triangle XYZ$ and intersect them with the lines of $\triangle ABC$ and use those points to create a third triangle.   But again, I can't easily infer the angles of the exterior one.

Comment: Judging by how the answer to the question appears to be irrational, I'd say an answer would require $\sin$ or $\arcsin$?

Comment: @MXYMXY Why would it need to be irrational?  In the puzzle, the OP agrues that it is an integer and asks for an answer that can make a good argument for why it is an integer.  Obviously, OP can be wrong, but I am taking it on faith that he knows what he is talking about.  Maybe he can answer this question! :P

Comment: @MXYMXY I should point out that in the puzzle, the given angles were all given as integers in degrees and the answer is also an integer.

Comment: Negative. The most downvoted answer, found through computer, seems to indicate it isn't, to be exact. There was rounding, but it should be able to determine whether it is a integer or not.

Comment: @MXYMXY That answer used an app with approximations based on a drawing, so yes, it would have rounding.  The highest voted answer uses trig functions and came up with 34 exactly.

Comment: If you actually do see the highest upvoted answer, one comment on it says that  
'I have seen some answers pointing in this general direction, but unless a sufficientely good approximation is accepted as an integer, this type of answer fails to prove that the angle is exactly an integer degree.' And the poster of the answer agrees. So it might not actually be 34, just a approximation, which is why I doubt that it is an integer.

Comment: I just trust computers more than humans in matters of calculations.

Comment: There is one tricky point --- your design is not an exact replica of the original puzzle. In the original puzzle, $\angle CSB = 24^0$ (corresponds to yours $\angle …$) which is exactly double that of $\angle ABH$.

Comment: @MXYMXY Take a look now.  It is proven to be an integer through trigonometric identities.  However, there is no geometric solution.

Comment: @Mick I never gave any numbers for this question.  I just generalized it.

Comment: I know. I am talking about the original puzzle. One angle is the double of the other might affect the deduction.